# Show subarray of color image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

Given a color image I need to show just a subpart of the image, in matlab this would be something like showing a subarray from array image.

```
I=imread('lena_std.tif');
imshow(I(1:200,1:200);
```

With a grayscale image the above code shows correctly the subpart of the image wanted, however with a color image it shows a grayscale image. I know there is a 3° dimension which in a color has a value of 3 (RGB), but I just don't know how to consider that dimension in order to show the subpart in color.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add to the code `:` to address all elements in third dimension:

```
I=imread('lena_std.tif');
imshow(I(1:200,1:200,:);
```